# Check for posted data inside the config file or form_validation.php in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check for a posted data if present so that I can set a form field as required or not, without having to create a custom rule.

Is it possible to use/load/call CodeIgniter's input library inside the config file (specifically the form_validation.php config file) and get user posted data without having to use the native $_POST variable?

my code goes something like this...

```
    ...
    array(
        'field' => 'dob_day',
        'label' => 'Day',
        'rules' => (($this->ci->input->post('include_person') === 'yes') ? 'required|' : '') . 'integer|max_length[2]|greater_than[0]|less_than[32]|valid_birth_date'
    ),
    ...
```

Obviously, my approach does not work. hehe. If there's an alternative efficient codeigniter way of doing what i'm thinking, please let me know.

Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[MANUAL](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrulesasarray)

try this example, in this mode you can at runtime change your rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dob_day', 'Day', 'your new rules');
```

Comment: i've also seen that. That is my current approach, but is there any cleaner way of adjusting the rules?

Comment: what i've found out actually after setting rules to the dob_day field in the controller, the set rules for all the other fields in the config were not implemented. sounds pretty bad.. i would not want to set rule for the other fields as well as it makes setting the rules redundant.

Comment: I don't think you can do this @bonbon.langes

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ended up with putting the logic in the controller, and just using inline validation. But to have inline validation work without having to set all the rules, I used the code from this website to allow both inline and config rules to mix.

http://brettic.us/2010/09/13/codeigniter-form-validation-mix-rule/

Cheers!